# Populate a Images in a Recyclerview using a single row and Expanded based on Content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to implement something similiar to how Instagram does there User Page, towards the bottom is a grid of images, that scrolls based on content, as I have been reading information on how to accomplish this, I've read it might be a hassle using a gridview in a recyclerview, So my question is can this be accomplished using a recycler view with just on card row and expanded based on the number of items returned from a database call, in code. I have included a basic image of what I am describing. Or would I have to implement this using a grid of cards.

I do have a custom header that sits above the list if that helps, and I want it to scroll, like that of Instagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways:

1. use a library that have header implemented.

I'm the devloper of this lib https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools. With this it's fairly easy to implement a header using:

```
GridLayoutManager glm = 
    new GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount); // make it into a grid
adapter = new Adapter(); // your adapter that contains the grid items
WrapAdapter wrapAdapter = new WrapAdapter(adapter); // wrap with the library
wrapAdapter.addHeader(header) // that's your header view
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(
   wrapAdapter.createSpanSizeLookup(spanCount)); // this is needed for the header width
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
recyclerView.setAdapter(wrapAdapter);
```

2. a different is doing what the library is doing internally, set a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) to the recyclerview and set a custom [SpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html) on it that tells the recyclerview to use the complete span count for the 1st item (header) and and a value of 1 for the others.

I Googled for 15seconds and this link seems to show how to do this second way http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html (alternatively u can check the source code of the library)

Comment: Thanks @Budius, that led me in the right direction, appreciate it

Comment: @Budius Eyeem android app is cool, smooth and rich UI. Can you tell me how did you managed that RecyclerView scrolling ?